# Async/Await for Synchronous Google Maps Elevation Request

Tags: typescript, google-maps-api-3, async-await

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to run this sequentially. I've tried all sorts of `Promise.all` and callback hell kinda stuff, but ultimately I need to get an elevation for each point that doesn't have `-1` for an altitude, and not return until all of them have been set.

Bonus points for only calling `google.maps.ElevationService.prototype.getElevationForLocations()` once with a filtered list where `ins instanceof PosInstruction && ins.$alt === -1`)

```
public async encodeElevations(): Promise<void> {
    let x = 0
    console.warn(x++, 'start')
    await this.$instructions.forEach(async (ins) => {
        console.warn(x++, 'topForEach')

        if (ins instanceof PosInstruction && ins.$alt === -1) {
            const reqPoint: google.maps.LocationElevationRequest = { locations: [ins.$latLng] }

            await google.maps.ElevationService.prototype.getElevationForLocations(reqPoint, async (results: google.maps.ElevationResult[], status) => {
                if (status === google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
                    console.warn(x++, 'status ok')
                    ins.setAlt(results[0].elevation)
                }
                else throw new Error(`encodeElevations() -- ${status.toString()}`)
            })

            console.warn(x++, 'after getElev')
        }
    })

    console.warn(x++, 'done')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `await getElevationForLocations`. It does not return `Promise`. It calls callback on completion which can be wrapped in a `Promise`:

```
public async encodeElevations(): Promise<void> {
    let x = 0
    console.warn(x++, 'start')
    const instructions = this.$instructions.filter(ins => ins instanceof PosInstruction && ins.$alt === -1);
    const promiseArray = instructions.map((ins) => {
      console.warn(x++, 'topForEach')
      const reqPoint: google.maps.LocationElevationRequest = { locations: [ins.$latLng] }
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        google.maps.ElevationService.prototype.getElevationForLocations(reqPoint, (results: google.maps.ElevationResult[], status) => {
          if (status === google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
            console.warn(x++, 'status ok')
            ins.setAlt(results[0].elevation)
            resolve(ins);
          } else {
            reject(new Error(`encodeElevations() -- ${status.toString()}`));
          }
        });

        console.warn(x++, 'after getElev')
      });
    })

    const array = await Promise.all(promiseArray);

    console.warn(x++, 'done')
  }
```